# Burned Up Trace on Input Cap

Tags: capacitor, dc-dc-converter, input

I'm working on a fairly simple PCB that interconnects three arduinos. There are also MOSFETs for switching some solenoids. The system runs off of a 24V DC power supply. I was running a LM7812 voltage regulator, but I added a pair of cooling fans and they draw about an amp combined so I switched out the LM7812 for a R-78B12-2.0 DC-DC regulator.

I dropped in the 78B12 and everything looked fine. I ran the pair of fans for a couple of hours and everything seemed good. Nothing was warm, voltages were stable. I dropped in my arduinos and fired it back up and clearly something went wrong.

The trace from from 3.3uF input cap on the 78B12 to ground was smoked and the 78B12 is now shorting 24V straight out. That blew up one of my Arduinos and both of my cooling fans.

I'm not sure where to start to diagnose what happened and would appreciate the help.

EDIT:
Here are my schematics (with fixed ground on U6 and correct C1)

[image: Schematic Page 1]
[image: Schematic Page 2]

Comment: There is insufficient information about the circuit.  You are going to have to provide a schematic before anyone can really help you.

Comment: There is no *3.3uF input cap* nor a *78B12*, please show the *complete* circuit. Do you have protection diodes anti-parallel to the solenoids?

Comment: Why is the COM not connected on U6? Where are the 3u3 caps mentioned in your post? Was the burnt trace a series connection between source and load?

Comment: Just uploaded the schematics. U6 COM is connected. I just added the R78B12 to the schematic and didn't draw that wire. The burnt trace was the connection between the ground pin of the cap and ground.

Comment: Boy, the input cap (C3) looks a little small (datasheet calls for something like a 4.7uF-10uF) and I am assuming that U6-2 is connected to GND.  And, as Huisman stated about the flyback diodes for the inductive loads.

Comment: The solenoids were not connected at this time. They have built-in flyback diodes.

Comment: Please give the *complete* description of C1. So, the correct value (3.3u as in question or 0.33u is in schematic??), voltage rating, brand, etc.

Comment: EDIT.  I fat-fingered (C3) and meant to type C1.

Comment: You are correct Huisman, I overlooked that. It is indeed a 0.33uF cap. It's a non-branded ceramic cap rated for 50V.

Comment: I swapped out the cap for a 10uF 25v electrolytic (all I had) and jumpered the ground trace. The regulator is working again. Is that what caused this?

Comment: Don't use a 25V rating. Use at least a rating of 1.5*24V = 36V, so 50V.

Comment: This was just a test. I only had a 25V laying around. I'm going to order the 50V.

Comment: Please add the board in the 2nd schematic to the 1st schematic.  Show how you are getting the 12v from the board in the 2nd schematic to the other 3 boards.  J2?  The melted trace indicates excessive current that happened when you "attached" adruinos to the 12V.  So it matters how these things are connected.

Comment: This is two sheets for one board.

Comment: @Huisman  Could you convert your comments into an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huisman was spot on. The issue was the improperly sized capacitor. Just posting this to close out the question.

Thanks!

Comment: Congrats with the solution. Good luck with the electronics!